# How to hide jquery ui tabs status bar URL

Tags: jquery

I use the method below to hide the status bar message.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onfocus="blur()" id="test">TEST</a>
$('#test).click(function(){ 
   ...
}
```

How can I hide the tabs status bar URL while i mouseover?

Comment: Change "click" to "mouseover?"

Comment: please explain with more details

Answer (score 2):

Use `hover()` method which manages both mouseenter and mouseleave.

```
$('#test').hover(function(){
   $('#statusElement').toggle()/* hide or show*/
})
```

`hover()` can also take a second function as argument for the `mouseleave` event

```
$('#test').hover(function(){
    /* first function is mouseenter*/
   $('#statusElement').show();
},function(){
    /* second function is mouseleave*/
   $('#statusElement').hide();
});
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Thank you for reply. But How can I do it on ui tabs? Please find the image at http://www.singinfo.com.sg/ask/tabs.png appreciate you can help

Comment: what do you want to hide? I don't know what a `tabs status bar` is and I've worked with tabs many many times. I assumed it was some element you created in your page

Comment: image shows browser hovered link status...what does that have to do with tabs?

Comment: I just don't want to show the URL on browser status bar while moouseover or click on the ui tabs element.

Comment: only thing you can do is adjust browser settings...but user has to do that

Comment: what is `#statusElement` ??? I am trying to do the same, but is there anyway to do it? because I don't understand what is #statusElement and how it will work.

Comment: @Krupa  it is a pseudo selector representing an element with `id="statusElement"` since no html specifics were given...adjust accordingly